# How can I map denormalized data to a complex object using automapper?

Tags: automapper

Assume I have 3 classes State and City and StateCities:

```
public class State {
   public string StateName;
   public List<City> Cities;
}

public Class City {
   public string CityName;
}

public Class StateCities {
   public string StateName;
   public string CityName;
}
```

I have a list of 3 StateCities objects with the following data (denormalized):

**StateName   CityName**

California     San Jose

California     Los Angeles

Florida         Miami

I want to map this list into a list of State objects, which should have 2 entries (California, Florida). The Cities field for the "California" object should have 2 entries (San Jose, Los Angeles) and the Cities field for the "Florida" object should have 1 entry (Miami).

I know of various ways to do this, but none seem to be simple or efficient. What is the best way to achieve this?

NOTE: I would prefer to use AutoMapper to map to and from a List of State objects to a list of StateCities objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your StateCitiesList by StateName and then map the Group

```
cfg.CreateMap<StateCities, City>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CityName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CityName));
cfg.CreateMap<IGrouping<string, StateCities>, State>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Cities, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ToList()));
```

Comment: Good answer! It correctly creates 2 State object and the correct List of City objects as described. However, I cannot use .ReverseMap() to map from a List of State objects to a List of StateCities object. Would I just need to write a separate mapping for that?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't noticed that you need to Reverse it. AutoMapper can't know how to implement `IGrouping<string, StateCities>`, but you can use a custom implementation of `IGrouping<,>` and map this. Or, the easier way, just add a mapping from `State` to `StateCities`